# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I coded this in attempt to find the duplicates in an array and increment the count each time a duplicate element was found, this program work but if I put an else statement after if statement the compiler prints off the else statement even though the array has duplicate elements...

```
  public class arraysexpmnt {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr={2,2,2,5,7,8,9,9,8,7};
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(arr[j]==arr[i]){
                count++;
                 System.out.println("Duplicate found! Original is " + arr[i] + " and match is " +arr[j]+" and the count of similar elements is "+count);
            }

        }

    }


}
```

}

Comment: This seems to work just fine. Could you explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: can you also post the code that is failing?

Comment: Maybe you want at the end of your code, outside of the `for` loop something like `if(count>0) System.out.println("no duplicates in the list.");`

Comment: Your output probably suggests that there are 2 additional 2's, then 3 additional 2's, then 4 additional 7's, then 5 additional 9's.  Is that the problem?

Comment: You may also get better performance if you _sort_ the array first, then find the indicies of the first and last instances of a duplicate.  This is, what, O(n^2)?  A sort (with a good algorithm) will cost O(n log n), then a single linear run through the array is O(n).

Comment: public class arraysexpmnt {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] arr={2,2,2,5,7,8,9,9,8,7};
  int count=0;
  for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
    if(arr[j]==arr[i]){
     count++;
             System.out.println("Duplicate found! Original is " + arr[i] + " and match is " +arr[j]+" and the count of similar elements is "+count);
    }
    else
     System.out.println("No Duplicates found");
    }
   
    }

 
    }
     }

Comment: the above snippet is my code, the code fails if I use else clause, why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the else clause gets executed whenever in the loop the two elements in the array do not match.. which is a quite common thing. put the same tracing println there and you'll see it.

Comment: in the else clause I've put a println statement it gets executed even if there are duplicates in the array... I mean if I remove else clause my program works wonder, but if I include one then it prints else clause no matter what...

Comment: yes it's get executed. that's **fine**. the only scenario where the else won't be executed ever is when the array contains only a  repeated element (eg: 2,2,2,2). You probably want to print something if the array doesn't contain duplicates (although you never told us this) and you want to do it with that else. that's **wrong**. read my answer again and think about it.

Comment: ok, I understand it now, what would I have to do if I want to printout that no elements in the array are duplicates...

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you look for is:

```
  public class arraysexpmnt {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] arr={2,2,2,5,7,8,9,9,8,7};
       int count=0;
       for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          boolean found = False;
          for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
             if(arr[j]==arr[i]){
                count++;
                System.out.println("Duplicate found! Original is " + arr[i] + " and match is " +arr[j]+" and the count of similar elements is "+count);
                found = True;
             }
           }
           if (!found) {
                System.out.println("No duplicate found for  Original: " + arr[i] );
           }
        }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me. If your code does not find duplicate elements in the current loop, it should execute the else clause as you say it is doing. If that is not the functionality that you want, then you have to change your logic.  What is it that you want your code to do?

Comment: in the else clause I've put a println statement it gets executed even if there are duplicates in the array... I mean if I remove else clause my program works wonder, but if I include one then it prints else clause no matter what...

Answer (score 0):

Your code outputs:

```
Duplicate found! Original is 2 and match is 2 and the count of similar elements is 1 
Duplicate found! Original is 2 and match is 2 and the count of similar elements is 2
Duplicate found! Original is 2 and match is 2 and the count of similar elements is 3
Duplicate found! Original is 7 and match is 7 and the count of similar elements is 4
Duplicate found! Original is 8 and match is 8 and the count of similar elements is 5
Duplicate found! Original is 9 and match is 9 and the count of similar elements is 6
```

If your array was sorted, then you could increment i whenever you find a matching j.  This would prevent the extra reports for more-than-3 situations.  You may also want to reset count on each `i` iteration.

Your array is not completely sorted, though.  Another approach may be desirable if you want to eliminate the duplication.

Comment: thank you mate... I was just checking a way to find duplicates in the array, I've tried your approach, it works like a wonder..